# Bridge connection windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, bridge, wireless-bridge

When I select wireless network connection and LAN connection and try to bridge connection, a pop-up box comes saying:

> To create a network bridge, you must select at least two LANS or high
>   speed internet connections that are not being used by internet
>   connection sharing

I do not understand what it is saying. I am trying to bridge a wi-fi connection that I get from my neighbour in my laptop with my desktop. Is that pop-up box pointing to this situation?

Comment: so your laptop is connected to your neighbor over wifi, and the laptops wired NIC is connected to the wired network that your desktop is connected to. is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must disable internet connection sharing on bout connections. Go to Start→Control Panel→Network and Sharing Center. Change adapter settings -> and for Lan and Wi-fi do this just opposite! [1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ifDyMaWC0Mk#t=140s) or [2](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-share-an-internet-connection-in-windows-7.html).

So you need to uncheck "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection check box".

Comment: on win 8 I was still getting that message until I selected both network interfaces and then right clicked on one and selected 'bridge interfaces'